# How Do You Focus The Android Developer Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, focus, emulation

I made an image button in eclipse and I ran it with the emulator in the android sdk package.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/cat1" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/cat2" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/cat3" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

"Pressed" and "Default" work with the mouse, but is there a way you can focus it? If you can't, do you need to emulate it on an actual android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the track ball or arrow keys to move around between your views.